# How to change date without making new http request

Tags: javascript, html, httprequest

I have this at the moment:

[image]

It is contained within a standard php/html/css page.

What would be the best way to incorporate the buttons, 'previous month' and 'next month' without making a new http request i.e. sending a $_GET to get the month & year, because I want to preserve any data the user inputs into the page.

How can I pass the month/year to the page itself so it can change respectively with the function that it uses to generate the calendar?

I guess that I would have to use jQuery/javascript/AJAX, i'm not the most experienced in these areas so any alternatives would be great.

So, how can I refresh the function with new parameters for the calendar? I pass my function the current month and year to generate my calendar:

HTML -

```
<form  action="this.php" id="PREVIOUS_MONTH" method="post">
<input type="submit"  value="Previous Month"/>
</form>
```

PHP -

```
function generateCalendar($month, $year){
.. generate calendar code
}
```

How can I use AJAX to refresh the function(generateCalendar) with new parameters i.e. a month before / year before, without making a new http request?

Thanks

Comment: There is good jqueryui datepicker widget, probably you can use it http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/#entry-examples

Comment: Show us your code that generates the calendar view. Yes, you will be able to build a JavaScript function to change the view without reloading the page.

Comment: @Bergi updated the code on the question, please re-read :)

Comment: Ajax always makes a HTTP request, so your question hardly makes sense.

Comment: @Bergi so what I intend to do is change the date when I click the previous month button. Is there anyway of re-running the PHP script, or would I have to do a POST and send a new HTTP request. Other people have said that I could use jQuery/Javascript/Ajax to get this effect.

Comment: @Chris: [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) means sending a HTTP request to your server (where the PHP runs then), but without reloading the whole page.

Comment: @Chris–you can either get a new component from the server (there are various ways to do that, XMLHttpRequest is common but not the only way) or generate it locally with script. Which is best for you depends on your requirements. Either way, you don't have to reload the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use javascript.
You can try jQuery, it's not hard to understand.

If you want to transfere data, check ajax :

Look here to play with ajax and jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you want a really tiny lib, try microajax : http://code.google.com/p/microajax/

```
microAjax("/my/url", function(resource) {
  alert("I load this : " + resource);
});
```